# How do I only plot the values I want?

Tags: python, math

I currently have the code and I having some trouble trying to plot it, I know that trying to plot both ymax and y won't work in this case, but how would I go about plotting just the value for y? I have plotted the function before by removing the ymax from the return, but I need to print the values and plot the solution for y.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def GaussElimination(A):
    '''
    Description: Use Gauss elimination to solve a set of simultaneous equations
    Parameters: A  a matrix of coefficient and constant value for the system
    Return: a matrix holding the solution to the equation.  This corresponds to the last n 
    '''
    nr,nc=A.shape
    B= A.copy()

    # start the gauss elimination
    for r in range(nr):
        #pivoting
        max=abs(B[r][r])
        maxr = r
        for rr in range(r,nr):
            if max < abs(B[rr][r]):
                max = abs(B[rr][r])
                maxr = rr

        if max == 0:
            print("Singular Matrix")
            return []

        # swap if needed
        if (maxr != r):
            for c in range(nc):
                temp = B[r][c]
                B[r][c]=B[maxr][c]
                B[maxr][c] = temp

        # scale the row
        scale = B[r][r]
        for c in range(r,nc):
            B[r][c] = B[r][c]/scale

        # eliminate values in the columns
        for rr in range(nr):
            if rr != r:
                scale = B[rr][r]
                for c in range(r,nc):
                    B[rr][c]=B[rr][c] - scale*B[r][c]

    if (nc == nr+1):
        return B[:,nc-1]
    else:
        return B[:,(nr):nc]

def SimplySupportedBeam(n):
    M = np.zeros([n+1,n+1])
    C = np.array([[0],[150],[0],[0],[0],[0]])
    for r in range(n-3):
        M[r][r] = 1
        M[r][r+1] = -4
        M[r][r+2] = 6
        M[r][r+3] = -4
        M[r][r+4] = 1

    M[n-3][1] = 1
    M[n-2][n-1] = 1

    M[n-1][n-5] = 1
    M[n-1][n-4] = -2
    M[n-1][n-3] = 1
    M[n][n-2] = 1
    M[n][n-1] = -2
    M[n][n] = 1

    A = np.concatenate((M,C), axis=1)
    y0 = GaussElimination(A)
    y = y0[1:n]
    ymax = np.amax(abs(y))

    return y, ymax



n = int(input("Index of the last node: "))
print (SimplySupportedBeam(n))

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(SimplySupportedBeam(n))
plt.show()
```

How would I plot just the value I get for y from my code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like y is 1D numpy array.

If you just want to plot its values against their indices you should be able to do so using either

```
plt.plot(SimplySupportedBeam(n)[0])
```

or

```
y, ymax = SimplySupportedBeam(n)
plt.plot(y)
```

The problem was that your function returns two values, i.e. `y` and `ymax`.
(I did not